# Is it possible to set a mouselistener in WPF?

Tags: wpf, mouse, listener

Can i set a mouselistener (Clicked) in WPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple,

- Just a **Click** attribute to your xaml control
- Assign it a handler
- Define the handler in your xaml.cs

In your xaml,

```
<Button Click="Button_Click"></Button>
```

In your xaml.cs,

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //What should be done when you click the control
    }
```

There are loads of mouse events available. Check MSDN for the [list of mouse events supported in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse_attachedevents.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If te user clicked where?
If you have a button(or window or pretty much anything else) you simpy add the MouseDown() eventhandler....